# How to add the attribute value for elements(with same name) in xml using SimpleXML PHP programatically

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Here i am creating nodes as a child to the AdSources node. I can able to create several nodes with same name "Ad". But i am not able to set the attribute("id") for each element("Ad"). If i try to set ID value for the second element, it says that this element already has the same attribute. i.e each time when i try to set id for it goes on to the first element alone.

```
$xmlFile    = 'mediationrequest2.xml';
$xml        = new SimpleXMLExtended('<Mediation  version="1.0"/>');
$adsources = $xml->addChild('AdSources');

$xml->AdSources[0]->addChild('Ad');
$xml->AdSources[0]->Ad->addAttribute('id', '1001');
$adsources->Ad[0]->addChild('Value', '5');
$adsources->Ad[0]->addChild('VASTAdTagURI');
$xml->AdSources[0]->Ad[0]->VASTAdTagURI->addCData('http://rtr.innovid.com/r1.515f10ae711057.99306980;cb=$rand');

$xml->AdSources[1]->addChild('Ad');
$xml->AdSources[0]->Ad->addAttribute('id', '1002');
$adsources->Ad[0]->addChild('Value', '5');
$adsources->Ad[0]->addChild('VASTAdTagURI');
$xml->AdSources[0]->Ad[0]->VASTAdTagURI->addCData('http://rtr.innovid.com/r1.515f10ae711057.99306980;cb=$rand');
```

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleXMLElement::addChild()` returns the new element object. Use the variable.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<Mediation  version="1.0"/>');
$adsources = $xml->addChild('AdSources');

$Ad = $adsources->addChild('Ad');
$Ad->addAttribute('id', '1001');
$Ad = $adsources->addChild('Ad');
$Ad->addAttribute('id', '1002');

echo $xml->asXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Mediation version="1.0">
  <AdSources><Ad id="1001"/><Ad id="1002"/></AdSources>
</Mediation>
```